# Question marks instead of Greek characters from Java HttpURLConnection InputStream

Tags: java, character-encoding, web-scraping

I am scraping some academic search portals for journal article titles, however one particular website is giving me question marks rather than the Greek letters (α,β,δ) which I do see when using a browser (Chrome).

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(currentUrl).openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
InputStream response = connection.getInputStream();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response, "UTF-8"));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
  sb.append(line);
}
```

After that code I search and get the titles, but as soon as reader.readLine() is called all of the Greek letters are question marks. The site claims to use UTF-8, and I have tried that and a variety of other character sets in my InputStreamReader. With ISO-8859-x encodings I get "Î´" and "??" for others (for US-ASCII too).

Sample URL: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=MiamiSearchURL&_method=submitForm&_acct=C000035118&_temp=search.tmpl&test_alid=&md5=aa8434c5674bd9954b705f429951f79d&SearchText=calmodulin&keywordOpt=11&addTerm=0&addSearchText=&addkeywordOpt=11&Subscribed=0&srcSel=18&srcSel=220&srcSel=21&srcSel=22&srcSel=23&C1=FLA&DateOpt=0&fromDate=2015&toDate=Present&aip=1&Volume=&Issue=&Page=&RegularSearch=Search&chunkSize=25

Comment: When I run your code against the specified URL, I see the Greek characters when I view the output in `vim`.  Is it possible that the terminal or application you're using to display the results is not configured to use UTF-8?

Comment: I'm using Eclipse. I am not at the computer I was using at the moment so I can't test it right now, but some Googling suggests that is possible. I had overlooked that since I had assumed Eclipse would properly handle the encoding specified by the code. Thank you, I will respond again when I can confirm by writing to a file and/or updating the Eclipse settings.

Comment: Eclipse defaults to the native platform's encoding.  So, if you're on Windows, that would be code page 1252, which would display the UTF-8 encoding of "α" (`\xCE\xB1`) as "Î±".  You can change the default text file encoding from **Window > Preferences > General > Workspace**.